# Configure to start new span in KafkaMessageListenerContainer not on listener (Kafka + Sleuth)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm new in kafka + sleuth. Currently I've faced with an issue, span creates in MessageListenerMethodInterceptor which triggers on KafkaListener, but in case of exception we are loosing spanId and traceId in ErrorHandler. Is it possible to configure sleuth to start span in KafkaMessageListenerContainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have handled it. In my local pc it works fine, but I have some doubts...

1. I disabled `MessageListenerMethodInterceptor` by setting `spring.sleuth.messaging.kafka.enabled=false` in application.properties
2. I created a record interceptor, implementation of `org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor` as following:

   ```
    private final Tracer tracer;
    private final KafkaTracing kafkaTracing;

    private static final ThreadLocal<Span> CURRENT_SPAN = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<Tracer.SpanInScope> CURRENT_SPAN_IN_SCOPE = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public ConsumerRecord<K, V> intercept(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
        openSpan(record);
        return RecordInterceptor.super.intercept(record, consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record, Exception exception, Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
        Span span = CURRENT_SPAN.get();
        if (span != null) {
            String message = Optional.ofNullable(exception.getMessage()).orElseGet(() -> exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
            span.tag("error", message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearThreadState(Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
        closeSpan();
    }

    private void openSpan(ConsumerRecord<K, V> record) {
        Span span = kafkaTracing.nextSpan(record).name("kafka-tracing").start();
        Tracer.SpanInScope spanInScope = tracer.withSpanInScope(span);
        CURRENT_SPAN.set(span);
        CURRENT_SPAN_IN_SCOPE.set(spanInScope);
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("created span {}", span);
        }
    }

    private void closeSpan() {
        Span span = CURRENT_SPAN.get();
        if (span != null) {
            try {
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOG.debug("finishing span {}", span);
                }
                span.finish();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.warn("on finishing Span {} got error {}", span, ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                CURRENT_SPAN.set(null);
            }
        }

        Tracer.SpanInScope spanInScope = CURRENT_SPAN_IN_SCOPE.get();
        if (spanInScope != null) {
            try {
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOG.debug("closing SpanInScope {}", spanInScope);
                }
                spanInScope.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.warn("on closing SpanInScope {} got error {}", spanInScope, ex.getMessage());
            } finally {
                CURRENT_SPAN_IN_SCOPE.set(null);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

other methods are empty.

The bean of this Interceptor created as follow:

```
    @Bean
    public KafkaTracingRecordInterceptor<Object, Object> kafkaRecordInterceptor(Tracer tracer, Tracing tracing) {
        return new KafkaTracingRecordInterceptor<>(tracer, KafkaTracing.create(tracing));
    }
```

PS. If I missed something or implemented it in wrong way please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The record interceptor is the best place to instrument; recent improvements expand its scope to include the error handlers.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1946

Comment: yes, I thought about record interceptor too. But when org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer#decorateException called, span.finished() already passed in org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.brave.instrument.messaging.MessageListenerMethodInterceptor#invoke ... or could you please provide an example how I can handle it?

Comment: The instrumentation needs to be moved from `MessageListenerMethodInterceptor` to a `RecordInterceptor` implementation.

Comment: Is there any elegant way to disable MessageListenerMethodInterceptor?

Comment: I added as new answer how I handle it, could you please check?

Comment: anyway thank you for the direction! @Gary Russell